# tmux session switcher now displays windows belonging to sesions

Tags: tmux

I recently compiled tmux from source rather than going through homebrew for some reason I can no longer recall. At the same time, switching sessions via `^b s`started to display all of the windows under each session, and not just the sessions thesmelves:

[Session Switcher Now](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9061771/Screenshots/9.png)

Is there any way I can revert to the previous behaviour of only displaying sessions and not the windows belonging to them as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default binding for <kbd>Prefix</kbd><kbd>s</kbd> was changed from `choose-session` to the new command `choose-tree` (i.e. choose from the tree of sessions and windows).

To revert to the old behavior, simply rebind `s` to `choose-session` (e.g. in your `.tmux.conf`):

```
bind-key s choose-session
```